# Android - MediaPlayer, how to catch broken url when streaming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, try-catch, android-mediaplayer

I have a little application that streams from differents urls from the net, I would like to handle invalid/broken url, I have tried the various catch offered but even when streaming a broken file, I can see my log in the log, all I see is

```
 Error (1,-1004)
```

here is my code for the moment

```
 mediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlString);
            Log.w("myApp", "0");
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            playPauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    textDuration.setText(getDurationString(duration/1000));
                    progress.setMax(duration);
                    playPauseButton.setChecked(true); 
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playPauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w("myApp", "1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w("myApp", "2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w("myApp", "3");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w("myApp", "4");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thank you for the help .)

Comment: What do you not try catch a generic Exception?  Then find out what type it is?  From the information posted, I can not tell where the exception is being thrown - if at all.

Comment: I'm very new to android coding, can you please explain me how to catch generic Exception?

Comment: catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("myApp", "5");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Also you try to debug, line-by-line to find out where it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener may help. it's not a exception.so you can't catch it.

```
onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra);
```

official doc. MEDIA_ERROR_IO is extra code.

```
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_IO

Added in API level 17
File or network related operation errors.

Constant Value: -1004 (0xfffffc14)
```

Comment: Probably the right answer, but just giving a link, has the danger that if the link becomes stale, nobody will know the answer.  Please expand

Answer (score 1):

This may help. If you are using Android Studio then watch the Run logs when you are debugging and it will show the error that is thrown.

e.g D/MediaPlayerNative: Message: MEDIA_ERROR(100), ext1=Unknown MediaErrorType(-38), ext2=0x0

This is the nearest I have got to seeing whether a stream is online or not.
If you know better please respond.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                switch (what) {
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Media Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Radio Server Died", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stream is possibly offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        button_stop.performClick();
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IO Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```